# How to reset Azure DevOps connector in MS Teams

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

I was moved from one DevOps organisation to another and access to the old org was removed. This caused my MS Teams DevOps plugin to stop working in private chats, but was fine in team channels.
[image: Permission error when trying to link an issue]
When I tried to open the app settings, I got a white window with a JSON that suggested a permission problem.

How do I connect the app to the new organisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to open the app settings using the [Teams webpage](https://teams.microsoft.com/) I got a popup that let me read the request URL and I saw the two GET parameters for organisation and project ID.
[image]
Removing those two parameters gave me a screen to select an organisation and a project. The tab closed right away and the integration is fixed.

I guess replacing the `project_id` and `tfs_uri` with the correct data from the target project would work, too, but that's the purpose of the section page, already.

Going to the app settings now yields this exact selection page, by the way, so this is a bug in the DevOps Teams app. There's one line of information at the top that apparently requires access to the DevOps organisation and needlessly gates the whole dialog behind organisation access permissions.

Comment: It's solved, thanks. I created a bug report at MS, too, unless you think I missed something.

Comment: Hi Randelung, if your issue has been solved, you can [mark your self answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Nd8.png), this will be helpful to other people who encounter the similar issue. Self answer need 48 hours after question created to be able to accept as the answer, you can do it later, thanks for your contribution in community!